# Как сохранить бинарные данные в json?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Здравствуйте! Возник такой вопрос: как сохранить бинарный файл (png) в памяти в поле Json::value (библиотека jsoncpp)? Мне это нужно для того, чтоб потом положить полученный json в couchbase с использованием libcouchbase. Бинарный файл я считываю в std::string и конвертирую в char * при помощи

```
std::ifstream fin("image.png", std::ios::binary);
std::string data;
data.reserve(1000000);
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
      std::back_inserter(data));
char *a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * data.length());
unsigned int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    a[i] = (unsigned char)(data[i]);
```

Поскольку я знаю длину строки, я могу вывести её полностью (просто вывод a не работает, т.к. в a есть символы конца строки). В результате a записывается и считывается из couchbase без изменений, это я проверил при помощи вывода в файл с получением картинки, тождественной исходной. Но мне нужно вместе с ней хранить ещё некие заголовки (тоже строки), поэтому хочется использовать json. Я пытаюсь сделать

```
Json::Value jsonvalue;
jsonvalue["value"] = a;
```

но при выводе jsonvalue["value"] в файл полученный файл уже не тождественен исходному. Подскажите, пожалйуста, что делать. Предполагаю, что я придумал неверное в принципе решение, как хранить картинки в couchbase вместе с заголовками. Но мне хотелось бы иметь возможнось в пределах одного запроса к базе получать как картинку, так и заголовки, поэтому я так поступил.

Comment: Используйте кодирование, например base64

Comment: Можно [data:URI схему](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL) использовать (поддерживается браузерами). В Питоне `data = urlopen('data:image/png;base64,...').read()` чтобы прочитать. Здесь [как закодировать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6375942/4279)

Comment: Спасибо. Кодирование полностью решило мою проблему. Использование data:URI выглядит интересно, буду разбираться.

Comment: Как оказалось, для хранения бинарных данных ещё удобнее использовать protozero, а не json. Просто записать всё в строку и положить её в couchbase, который поддерживает хранение не только json, но и бинарных документов.